# Progress bar update on Swiping fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, progress-bar

Im creating an application to show data in progress bar based on the selected fragment , so if particular fragment is selected the progress bar should show the data in that fragment and so on , in my application there are three fragments the data in progress bar gets updated for two fragments and not working for the third one ,ive tried with log everything looks fine ,,Ive tried giving logs and what ive figued out is that the fragment that is being opened is only two of them and im not getting the third log , even when i open the third fragment,and im getting an indication of opening the third fragment if i again move back to the second fragment,i cant figure out where im missing it .  below is my code

```
public class History extends Fragment {
     final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
     private String tabTitles[] = new String[]{"Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3"};
     public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

    private static final int NUM_PAGES =3;

    String medicinename,medicinepercentage,numberdosages,time;
    String date,day,daypercentage;
    String month,monthdata;

    /**
     * The pager widget, which handles animation and allows swiping horizontally to access previous
     * and next wizard steps.
     */
    private ViewPager mPager;

    /**
     * The pager adapter, which provides the pages to the view pager widget.
     */
    private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;


    private int selectedPage; // set selected page

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    DonutProgress dp;
    DonutProgress dp2;
    DonutProgress dp3;

    public static History newInstance(int page) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
        History fragment = new History();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private Paint progressPaint = new Paint();
    private int lineHeight = 30;
    private Paint incompletePaint = new Paint();

    public History() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment History.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static History newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        History fragment = new History();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

        dp = (DonutProgress) v.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress1);
        dp2 = (DonutProgress) v.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress2);
        dp3 = (DonutProgress) v.findViewById(R.id.donut_progress3);
        new Progress(0).execute();
        new Progress2(0).execute();
        new Progress3(0).execute();



        if (getArguments() != null)
        {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);

        }

        mPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager); //the UI pager
        mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
        // mPager.setPageTransformer(true, new RotateDownTransformer()); //set the animation

        selectedPage = 0; //current page
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { //if app was paused, you can reopen the same page
            selectedPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_PAGE");
        }
        selectedPage = 1; //current page
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { //if app was paused, you can reopen the same page
            selectedPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_PAGE");
        }
        selectedPage = 2; //current page
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { //if app was paused, you can reopen the same page
            selectedPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_PAGE");
        }

        selectedPage = 3; //current page
        if (savedInstanceState != null) { //if app was paused, you can reopen the same page
            selectedPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("SELECTED_PAGE");
        }


        mPager.setCurrentItem(selectedPage); //set the current page

        return v;


        // return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);

    }


    private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        int i = 0;
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                    Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 1::"+String.valueOf(i));

                        new Progress(100).execute();
                        new Progress2(20).execute();
                        new Progress3(30).execute();

                    return SlideFragment.newInstance(String.valueOf(0), " ");

                case 1: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                    Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 2");

                        new Progress(40).execute();
                        new Progress2(50).execute();
                        new Progress3(90).execute();

                    return Slidetwo.newInstance(String.valueOf(1), " ");
                case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                    Log.e("Fragment","Fragment 3");

                        new Progress(50).execute();
                        new Progress2(10).execute();
                        new Progress3(0).execute();

                    return SlideThree.newInstance(String.valueOf(2), " ");

                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount()
        {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }


    }


    class Progress extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
        {
            int dummyVariable = 1;
            Progress(int dummyVariable)
            {
               this.dummyVariable = dummyVariable;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                dp.setMax(100);
             // Progress.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#C0D000"), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i <= dummyVariable; i++)
                {
                    publishProgress(i);
                    try
                    {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ie)
                    {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                dp.setProgress(values[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
                super.onPostExecute(integer);
            }
        }

        class Progress2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {
            int dummyVariable = 0;
            Progress2(int dummyVariable)
            {
                this.dummyVariable = dummyVariable;
            }


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                dp2.setMax(100);
            }

            @Override
            protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= dummyVariable; i++) {
                    publishProgress(i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(20);
                    }
                    catch (InterruptedException ie)
                    {
                        ie.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);

                dp2.setProgress(values[0]);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
                super.onPostExecute(integer);
            }
        }


    class Progress3 extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer>
    {

        int dummyVariable = 0;
        Progress3(int dummyVariable)
        {
            this.dummyVariable = dummyVariable;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dp3.setMax(100);
        }

        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= dummyVariable; i++) {
                publishProgress(i);
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(20);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie)
                {
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            dp3.setProgress(values[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Integer integer) {
            super.onPostExecute(integer);
        }
    }


        // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set offscreenPaginglimit?
Try setting

```
yourViewPager.setOffScreenPagingLimt=2;
```

Let me know if this helps  out!

Comment: If i set setOffscreenPageLimit(2) None of the circular progress bars works when i swipe the fragments .

Comment: Try changing the index. Make it to zero.

Comment: Actually the Progress bar changes data when i swipe to second fragment and swiping to third fragment nothing changes , again if i swipe from third to second fragment the data for third fragment is getting displayed.and for changing this index to zero same thing is happening .